# Running Windows 7 on VMWare

Tags: vmware-server, windows-7

Was wondering if there were any issues with running the newest Windows 7 iso on VMWare server?

Answer (score 1):

I ran it successfully on ESX 3i just last week.  There were no apparent issues other than not being able to realize the full capabilities of the new Aero interface since the VMware ESX Server I have is not designed for a lot of 3D acceleration.

Comment: what about on VmWare Server?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a look at this VMWare produced document it gives a run down on a huge number of OSs and points out any potential problems. [Guest OS guide](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/GuestOS_guide.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

On certain builds of VMWare Workstation 6.5.1, A blue screen is received on install. 6.5.2 Fixes this issue.
Other than that, Windows 7 isn't much different than Vista, so if you can get Vista to run under VMWare, so you could get 7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running it without issues (thus far) on VMWare Fusion on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I have been running Win7 Beta under Workstation 6.5.2 without issue.